# How to set form action to default contact form action

Tags: forms, emails

I'm editing a Drupal site, it has a hardcodeded contact form which I would like to have the same behaviour than the default contact form (applying filters, inserting info in the database and sending email).

Maybe it is an easy question but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can somebody help me with this please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I not sure will this help you. If you have no other solution, how about try to use webform module with form builder. I not sure what you mean filter, but its help to store in database and send email easily.

Hope this help you.

[image]